# Is there a way to autosave in Dungeons of Dredmor?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

Dredmor is a fun game, but it occasionally crashes on my computer.  Therefore, I end up saving often to avoid losing progress.  Going into the menu to save means that first I have to close all of my sub screens (ie, I have to close my inventory, dismiss my Lutefisk cube, close my character window, etc).  This is kind of irritating.  I'd prefer some sort of auto-save feature, or, failing that, a quicksave button.

Is there some way to do this in Dredmor?  I haven't found anything in any of the menus about this.  I've seen that the game supports mods, but I don't know where to look for Dredmor mods, and if one of this type exists.

Comment: Do you really have to close all the windows? If you get to the menu via "escape" it does close everything, but if you just click the "menu" button with the mouse it shouldn't force you to close those windows...

Comment: I've tried via the "M" key and using "Escape" and both force me to close all windows (except the crafting interface, oddly enough).  I'll see if pressing the menu button is any different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The game automatically saves whenever you switch floors. My anti-crash approach is, whenever I pass a staircase (either up or down), take it and immediately return. Staircases are common enough that this is a pretty effective way of periodically saving. It also works in permanent-death mode.

Just be careful - steps to unvisited areas can lead you to a room full of monsters, and even stairs to a visited location may be dangerous, since monsters slowly spawn in visited areas. So although it's usually easy to get back, don't do this if you're really low on health.

Comment: This is interesting, I'll keep it in mind.  My only issue is that my current strategy keeps me locked in certain rooms for a long time (see my other DoD question for today) so I don't always have a staircase handy.